# How to close a popup with swipe down in Framework7?

Tags: javascript, html-framework-7

I want to be able to close my popup on pull down event, but nothing like that appears in Framework7 docs. Is there some other solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with [Hammer library](http://hammerjs.github.io/).

Create your Hammer instance, set your direction (vertical here) and subscribe to `swipedown` event to call closeModal for the popup

Comment: There is one problem that i can see with this. My popup is scrollable so i need to trigger swipedown event only when i am on top of popup and user swipedown. Can you think of some solution for this?

Comment: Hmmm..... I haven't solution for that. But you can do somes things with popup position, or if top of popup is visible or not